# numerical values for the solution of NDEigensystem

Tags: differential-equations

I tried to solve Schrödinger equation in 3D box using the NDEigensystem. 
My code is:
`{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-1/
     2  (Div[Grad[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]), 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]}, 
   u[x, y, z], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 2];`

How I can extract the numerical values of the u[x,y,z]?
For example u[0,0,0?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{-1/2 (Div[Grad[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]), 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]}, u[x, y, z], 
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 2];
```

Then the value of `u[0,0,0]` for the eigenstates are

```
Table[funs[[i, 0]][0, 0, 0], {i, Length[funs]}]
(* {0.353627, 0.000205384} *)
```

You can also plot the solution:

```
Table[DensityPlot3D[Abs@funs[[i]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
    PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], 
    ImageSize -> Medium], {i, Length[vals]}] // Row
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for answer :)